# Display Text below image

Tags: html, css

I have an image with a hyperlink and would like to display the text below the image.

[Edit]
My output should be like under scorecards I need to see one image(google) with its text below it and under Dashboard, I need to see two images(amazon,microsoft) with its text below it.

Below image is the what I am expecting

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VAJF.jpg)

Below is the code

```html
<div class="innerDiv" id="Scorecards">
  <br>Scorecards<br>
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img class="imgCustom" id="menuImages" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/44/44357.svg">
    <span>Google</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="innerDiv" id="Dashboards">
  <br>Dashboards<br>
  <a href="https://abc.aspx">
    <img class="imgCustom" id="menuImages" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/3d-social/64/Online-writing-icon.png">
    <span>Microsoft</span>
  </a>

  <a href="https://cde.aspx">
    <img class="imgCustom" id="menuImages" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/babasse/old-school/64/old-videos-icon.png">
    <span>Amazon</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: A simple `<br>` between them doesn't work?

Comment: Thats not a good example of "good" HTML @j08691

Comment: @Pingbeat No? Please explain why not.

Comment: Why should you? spans are inline-elements, so you WANT them to align to the right of other items... inserting a simple <br> wouldnt work anyway...

Comment: @Pingbeat So you're saying that inserting a `<br>` between the `<img>` and `<span>` wouldn't cause the text to display below the image? You sure about that?

Comment: I thought you wanted to insert it INSIDE the span. Sorry for the missunderstanding. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its always good to take help of css to do the stylings that you want to make. While there might be many options for you to do achieve this result, here is one that I think will help you. https://jsfiddle.net/cc912995/

```css
.link span {
  text-align: center;
  display:block;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="innerDiv" id="Scorecards">
<br>Scorecards<br>
<a href="https://google.com" class="link"><img class="imgCustom" id="menuImages" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/44/44357.svg"><br><span>Google</span></a>
</div>

<div class="innerDiv" id="Dashboards">

<br>Dashboards<br>
<a href="https://abc.aspx" class="link">
<img class="imgCustom" id="menuImages" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/3d-social/64/Online-writing-icon.png"><br>
<span>Microsoft</span>
</a>

<a href="https://cde.aspx" class="link">
<img class="imgCustom" id="menuImages" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/babasse/old-school/64/old-videos-icon.png"><br>
<span>Amazon</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="innerDiv" id="Scorecards">
<br>Scorecards<br>
<a href="https://google.com"><img class="imgCustom" id="menuImages" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/44/44357.svg"><div>Google</div></a>
</div>

<div class="innerDiv" id="Dashboards">

<br>Dashboards<br>
<a href="https://abc.aspx"><img class="imgCustom" id="menuImages" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/aha-soft/3d-social/64/Online-writing-icon.png"><div>Microsoft</div></a>

<a href="https://cde.aspx"><img class="imgCustom" id="menuImages" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/babasse/old-school/64/old-videos-icon.png"><div>Amazon</div></a>
</div>
```

Use a DIV instead of spans.. Spans are Inline-Elements. Divs are block elements, wich makes them to align below another div.

Comment: Under Dashboard, I have two images they should be adjacent to each other. I am expecting under scoreboard, I need to see Google with its image and under dashboard I need to see Microsoft and amazon.

Comment: Could you clear out what you mean and what you want to achieve? I dont really get what you want...

Comment: I had attached the image in the question. please check

Answer (score 1):

**Use Div instead span**

The display property of the span is Inline

– The inline elements line up horizontally as like

Inline Inline Inline

The display property of the div is block

– The Block elements stack one on top of the other  as like the blocks

Use  over

**but if you still willing to use span, there are some tweaks you can apply**

1. use **br** before **span**
2. or make `#Scorecards a span, #Dashboards a span{
               display:block;
                   }`

the both hacks will help you to achieve your goal.

working example : https://jsfiddle.net/ishusupah/rknyddp0/